# Java8 LocalDateTime to XMLGregorianCalender Remove "+05:30" Portion

Tags: java-8, java-time

Did like below,

```
LocalDateTime currentUTCTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
String reqPattern = currentUTCTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS"));
System.out.println("Required pattern: " + reqPattern);
GregorianCalendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.from(currentUTCTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
XMLGregorianCalendar xcal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
System.out.println("But Showing As :" + xcal);
```

I want the output as `2015-06-18 11:59:15:135`, but when i set the `xcal` to 
a XML tag which takes `XMLGregorianCalender`, it shows like `2015-06-18T11:59:15.135+05:30`.

How can i remove the `+05:30` portion?

Comment: Have you tried `DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(currentUTCTime.toString())` using the lexical representation in ISO-8601?

Comment: @Meno Hochschild: No i didnt. But tried now and it works fine. Thank You very Much. Can you please Post this answer so i can mark it as solved and pick it as solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Use this code:**

```
LocalDateTime currentUTCTime = LocalDateTime.now(); // using system timezone
String iso = currentUTCTime.toString();
if (currentUTCTime.getSecond() == 0 && currentUTCTime.getNano() == 0) {
    iso += ":00"; // necessary hack because the second part is not optional in XML
}
XMLGregorianCalendar xml =
  DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(iso‌​);
```

**Explanation:**

The code makes use of the given [factory method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar-java.lang.String-) expecting a lexicographical representation of a local timestamp in ISO-8601-format. And since a `LocalDateTime` does not refer to any timezone, its output via `toString()` cannot contain a timezone offset. Result: `XMLGregorianCalendar` considers the timezone offset as "not set".

**Correction:**

The original code did not especially bother about the ISO-variant of formatted output of `currentUTCTime.toString()`. However, the `java.time-API` produces an output without seconds or nanoseconds if those parts are equal to zero. This is perfectly legal in ISO, but the W3C-consortium has made the second part non-optional. And the class `XMLGregorianCalendar` closely follows this deviating spec. Therefore the shown hack above using simple string concatenation in this special edge case. Thanks a lot to @Dave's comment. By the way, using `currentUTCTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)` as suggested in this comment is also possible (instead of the shown hack).

Comment: This doesn't work. What you want is DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(currentUTCTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)). XMLGregorianCalendar.newXMLGregorianCalendar(String) requires that its argument have the seconds populated. If seconds == 0 LocalDateTime.toString() will omit the seconds and its preceding : separator completely causing the calendar factory method to throw an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: @Dave Have now adjusted my answer.

Comment: It would be better to use a formatter than the if statement hack